# What's the difference between Selenium and selenium gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, selenium

A newbie question on Selenium for Ruby. What's the difference between "gem install selenium" and "gem install Selenium"? I'm trying to figure out which one I should install.

Answer (score 1):

I always used:

```
$ gem install selenium-client
```

I think that's the official one, but I can't find a place where it says this.

Once you installed it, all you have to add to your tests is:

```
require "test/unit"
require "rubygems"
gem "selenium-client", ">=1.2.16"
require "selenium/client"

class ExampleTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    attr_reader :browser

  def setup
    @browser = Selenium::Client::Driver.new(...
```